# Devdemon forms return url without ugly gray EE "thanks" page first

Tags: forms, devdemon

I have this:

```
{exp:forms:form
            form_name="contact"
            return="kontakt/takk"
            attr:class="form default contact"}

            {forms:fields}
                {forms:field}
            {/forms:fields}

            {forms:form_errors} {/forms:form_errors}

            <p class="denote center">Du hører fra oss innen 24 timer. <br><strong>Takk for at du vurderer oss!</strong></p>

        {/exp:forms:form}
```

And while i am returned to "kontakt/takk", that only happens after forms redirects to EEs ugly gray "thank you box". Is there a way to bypass that?

Answer (score 2):

Realized i could go to user messages and add
    a meta refresh with 0 seconds

Answer (score 2):

I like to use [Custom System Messages](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages) to avoid the EE default pages.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an option under "Submission Flow" to change it. You have four different options.

Confirm Message Behavior

1) Before Redirecting

2) On the confirmation page

3) Only Show Message (no redirect)

4) Just Redirect (no confirmation)

You are looking for "Just Redirect"

[image: Submission Flow]